# How to change subscription plan using subscription update API of openpay

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I need to update the subscription plan using update subscription API.

Ex. I have one subscription with plan monthly. Now i want to give user an ability such that thay can upgrade or downgrade the plan.so if user wants to upgrade the plan to yearly for the same subscription then how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

First you want to check here may be your problems solutions come here: `

[click here](https://www.openpay.mx/en/docs/suscriptions.html) for subscription regarding information.